# Why typescript does not have "function" type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I'm a typescript beginner and I'm wonderig why I can't do this:

```
const obj: {
  property1: string
  property2: boolean
  property3: function
}
```

I think the only alternative is by doing:

```
const obj: {
  property1: string
  property2: boolean
  property3: any
}
```

Why I must implement the **function** on **property3** inmediately on the object declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript does have a `Function` type, meaning a function that takes arguments `any` and returns a result of `any`, although I would highly recommend you not use it.

Instead you should use a [function signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types) that allows you to specify the parameter types and the return type explicitly :

```
let obj: {
  property1: string
  property2: boolean
  property3: (a: string, b: boolean) => number
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgLggbwFAQgBwE5UybMATwEYkBnMbASwDsBzdLXfQogJiRiilAENaTHHgLEAzEgAUfClTr0ANBBhce-WgEoIAXgB8EWgFcAtjAKoAvkA)

Answer (score 0):

The property must be implemented because it is part of the type of `obj`

If you do not want to initialize the property on declaration it must be made optional.

For example:

```
const obj: {
  property1: string
  property2: boolean
  property3?: any
}
```

Now you can do:

```
obj = { property1: 'A string'. property2: true };
```